# Importing HTML into Another HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I know this question has been asked a few times, however, after countless hours troubleshooting I unable to figure this one out on my own. Simply, I am building a large website and would like the header and footer to import via JavaScript when the page loads. Simple right! For some reason, I am missing something so here is the code below. After researching, it looks like JQuery is the favorite for this task, however, I have developed everything else without needing JQuery so if you know of a way to do it in straight JS then I would be very appreciative! Below is my process:

I am trying to import `view/header.html` into `index.html`. I am using the code below on the `index.html` page.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"></script>

<div id="navbarContent"></div>

<script>
   $( "#navbarContent" ).load( "view/header.html" );
</script>
```

I have attempted to load it on both local hosts and on the web with no success. Thanks!

Comment: Do you have any error messages in the console?

Comment: the only message I get is "$ is not defined"

Comment: Are you sure you imported jQuery correctly? Try entering `$` into the console.

Comment: It might also be because you are calling `$.load` before the element is actually created so try wrapping it in `$.ready` (https://api.jquery.com/ready/)

Comment: oh my! I figured out my mistake. I added the `defer` tag to all my JS links, which of course means it didn't load until after everything else. Thank you for troubleshooting with me! :)